# How to check mute or unmute while screen recording swift

Tags: ios, swift, recording

I've used RPSystemBroadcastPickerView to record screen. (BroadcastExtension)
I have to know mute/unmute status while screen recording.
So please let me know how to check it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In sampleBuffer, you have options for audio.

```
override func processSampleBuffer(_ sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, with sampleBufferType: RPSampleBufferType)
```

where RPSampleBufferType has audio options.

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
public enum RPSampleBufferType : Int, @unchecked Sendable {

    
    case video = 1

    case audioApp = 2

    case audioMic = 3
}
```

You have to check both `.audioApp` & `.audioMic`.

Now print those values in processSampleBuffer methods. There should have level options as far as I can remember. try to extract the audio level from the metadata. If the audio level is under a threshold value then it is mute otherwise on. The threshold value is completely up to you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Could you provide me detailed example code block?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any related code block right now. In my feature, I didn't have to handle your conditions.

Comment: how to get audio level from metadata?